# How is a neutron produced in a hydrogen fusion?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, hydrogen

So during a fusion reaction, a hydrogen atom (which consists of only a electron and proton) fuses with another hydrogen atom to produce deuterium which contains a proton and neutron. My question how does the neutron come out of nowhere when we have only 2 protons as the raw materials and where does the other neutron go. I know it could be a silly question but i searched and didn't understand the concept. So i came here to clarify my doubt.
Please explain in simple language.

Comment: Doubt is the basis of science. Good for you for doubting and asking questions. Never apologize for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time, proton-proton fusion results in the brief creation of a very unstable di-proton, which immediately decays into a pair of protons.

But *very* occasionaly, during the brief moment they are together, one of the protons will undergo a weak force interaction, changing one of its quarks from up to down, hence making a neutron, and  emitting a positron and an electron-neutrino in the process.
$$ p \rightarrow n + e^+ + \nu_e$$

The resulting proton-neutron pair can form a stable deuterium nucleus that is then the starting point for the production of helium. The creation of deuterium in this way is rare, because the conversion of a proton to a neutron is (a) endothermic, requiring energy; and (b) slow, moderated by the weak interaction, and thus the di-proton normally decays first. That is why the Sun will survive for about 10 billion years in total as a main sequence star, and why the centre of the Sun generates less heat per unit volume than a compost heap.

Comment: I had a doubt that if fusion is generating less heat than compost then why are scientists working so hard to achieve fusion?

Comment: @bhavesh Not by fusing protons! And using a much higher temperature than the centre of the Sun. The ITER tokamak aims to make 500MW from 860m$^3$ of reactor volume - about 2000 times the power density in the solar core.

Comment: so what is ITER tokamak fusing to achieve this?

Comment: @Bhavesh Deuterium and tritium  https://www.iter.org/sci/whatisfusion